# A recurrence Relations problem that I found in a manga

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

So this question is from the manga series, “Assassination Classroom”.
[The Japanese Roughly above given on the cyborg translates to](https://ibb.co/Mnph6YP): “Find the general solution for a[n] as defined in following recurrence-relation sequence.”

[The recurrence relation sequence in this scan looks something is shown at the bottom of that cyborg](https://ibb.co/TThqv5j)

[Here’s a drawing of mine trying to depict said recurrence relation clearly.](https://ibb.co/pL3JCD7)

I’m not sure if something like that would count as a recurrence relation or if the vertical “=“ signs are actually quotations (“ “)

Anyway, a [character “solves” the question and has written the solution (or at least, a trick) on a grenade.](https://ibb.co/album/dtPspZ):
a[n+1]/3[n+1] and a[n]/3[n]

So, can somebody help me interpret what the recurrence relation in the question is and what the steps are to finding the solution?

Thank you.

Comment: I don't understand the kind of information that can be exploited in your drawing neither the meaning that is attributed to $3[n]$ or $3[n+1]$

Comment: I appreciate the attempt, but I think there’s not enough information here to determine if this is real math or just a bunch of random symbols.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sometimes japanese is written vertically top to bottom, right to left. So the recurrence in the manga is
$$
\begin{align}
a_{1} &= 5,  \\
a_{n+1} &= 2a_{n} + 3.
\end{align}
$$
I don't see any relation between the symbols on the grenade and the solution the recurrence.

This can be solved by subtituting $a_{n}-2a_{n-1}$ into $3,$ which yields
$$
a_{n+1} = 3a_n - 2a_{n-1}.
$$
This is a homogeneous linear recurrence, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/254403/how-to-solve-second-degree-recurrence-relation) is one way to solve it. The final solution of this recurrence is
$$
a_{n} = 2^{n+2}-3.
$$

Comment: Another way to solve this is to add 3 to both sides of the initial recurrence to get $a_{n+1}+3=2(a_n+3)$. So $a_n+3$ doubles on each iteration, and since $a_1+3=8=2^3$ we have $a_n+3=2^{n+2}$.

Comment: Yea this sounds about right. Thank you for your help :D.